# Unable to execute shell from web server

Tags: shell, php, http

When ever I am trying to execute php script from web server, it fails:

[image]

```
cat test.sh
echo "Hello World"
[root@yumserver ~]#
```

I am trying to build a button on webpage through which I can push the script to the background..

nohup test.sh &

Please find below the permission/ownership details:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 apache apache 62 Mar 28 04:14 run.php 
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 62 Mar 27 06:33 sync.php
```

Even I tried CGI-bin but specific script is not getting executed..

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""
echo "<html><head><title>Bash as CGI"
echo "</title></head><body>"
echo "<h1>General system information for host $(hostname -s)</h1>"
echo ""
echo "<h1>Memory Info</h1>"
echo "<pre> $(free -m) </pre>"
echo "<h1>Disk Info:</h1>"
echo "<pre> $(df -h) </pre>"
echo "<h1>Logged in user</h1>"
echo "<pre> $(w) </pre>"
echo "<h1>test</h1>"
echo "<pre> $(sh /var/www/cgi-bin/yumsync.sh) </pre>"  <<<<<
echo "<pre> $(nohup uln-yum-mirror &) </pre>"  <<<<<
echo "<center>Information generated on $(date)</center>"
echo "</body></html>"
```

yumsync or uln-yum-mirror is the script which I am trying to push it to the background but it's not getting initiated.
Any suggestion what could be the cause?

Comment: what is expected result, how do you know it fails?

Comment: I should say "fail" is a wrong word but test.sh should give me an output like "Hello World" which confirms i'll be able to execute the script but right now its just showing the content of the script rather than result

Comment: is your werbserver able to execute the script (check ownership, groups, etc) ? is your php configuration allowed to execute scripts which are in the root's directory ?

Comment: Please find below the permission/ownership details:
-rwxrwxrwx 1 apache apache   62 Mar 28 04:14 run.php
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root   root     62 Mar 27 06:33 sync.php

Comment: Please add any further information into your question (by clicking on the `edit` link) instead of posting it as a comment.

Comment: More details are being updated..Either ways will work for me, Just want to push that script to the backend

Comment: please also 1. add permissions for /root/test.sh and 
2. confirm  apache is the user php runs under

Comment: @Tagwint Thats already been done..

/root/test.sh
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 19 Mar 27 03:37 test.sh

/var/www/html/yum/Backup
-rwxrwxrwx 1 apache apache   62 Mar 28 04:14 run.php

Comment: pls post your `httpd.conf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server error logs will almost certainly give you the reason.
Assuming it is apache web server, depending on your distro it can be either

```
/var/log/httpd/error_log
```

or

```
/var/log/apache2/error.log
```

you can conviniently check them with `tail` or `less`

Comment: Thanks Tagwint.. That helped alot.

[Mon Mar 28 06:36:25.157815 2016] [cgi:error] [pid 1074] [client 10.47.94.154:60764] AH01215: /usr/bin/uln-yum-mirror: You must be root to run this script,